# Kestrel port settings under VS2017 are ignored

Tags: visual-studio-2017, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I have an issue with starting Kestrel server from VS2017. In VS2015 in `launchSettings.json` I was able to set the port like this:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5010/api",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5010"
}
```

Now this setting is ignored by kestrel. If I change the name of the setting to: `"ASPNETCORE_SERVER.URLS"` I'm getting the warning about the setting being deprecated, which suggests that the `launchSettings.json` file is still being processed.

I also tried other options of setting the port - setting environment variable (`ASPNETCORE_URLS`) still works, but using `dotnet run --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:5010` doesn't.

Comment: Have got the same issue.

But ASPNETCORE_URLS worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On VS2017 something like this works for me

```
"profiles": {
    "Kestrel": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:2287"
    }
}
```

Running the app on port 2287